# Unity How to play footsteps sound with animation culled？

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, animation, audio

I'm working on a multiplayer the third peroson game project.For performance reasons, we need to cull animators when other players are out of sight.For example:When player B appears in my view, the animation component of Player B is enabled;When player B leaves my line of sight,the animation component of Player B is close(not enabled).Back to the problem: Locally, I couldn't play PlayerB's footsteps based on PlayerB's animation when PlayerB was out of sight(Because Player B's animation component is now off).
In such cases, the only solution seems to be to use logic to control footstep sound playback. Has anyone had a similar problem, and is there a better solution to play footstep sound when the animator is not enable?

Answer (score 0):

try out this
when animation is on add bool variable true and play sound when this bool true

when player B is out of frame animation is off , set bool false and if bool false sound is not play

Comment: otherwise as per Bool value sound mute and unmute as per requiment

Comment: I am sorry that if my expression was not very accurate. when an enemy appears behind the player,even though the enemy's animator was turned off, we still had to play footsteps to alert the player

Comment: I have updated my question description in the hope that this will help respondents better understand it.